# How to read labels of character tables in SageMath (and GAP)?

Tags: representation-theory, characters, sagemath

*Note: SageMath's `Group.character_table()` method is built as a wrapper for GAP's `CharacterTable()` function.*

Let $G = \text{Sym}_4$.
I would like to be able to extract the character of $G$ indexed by a given partition, say $\lambda = (3,1)$.

I have looked for this online and it seems like this is possible to do in GAP. However, I am struggling to translate GAP commands to SageMath commands in a way that works.

Minimal working example:

```
sage: G = SymmetricGroup(4)
sage: G.character_table()
[ 1 -1  1  1 -1]
[ 3 -1 -1  0  1]
[ 2  0  2 -1  0]
[ 3  1 -1  0 -1]
[ 1  1  1  1  1]
sage: lam = Partition([3,1])
```

I want to find a few lines of code that take `G` and `lam` and output the character `char` such that

```
sage: type(char)
<class 'sage.groups.class_function.ClassFunction_gap'>
sage: char.values()
(3  1 -1  0 -1)
```

or something similar.

Comment: Why should this question be closed ? As there exist a "sagemath" tag, it is normal to ask such a question whose mathematical content is far from being void (connection between characters of a group and partitions representation.

Comment: Yeah I don't agree with it closing. In the community guidelines, it says "we welcome questions about: [...] software that mathematicians use."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is, just one line:

```
sage: char = SymmetricGroupRepresentation(lam).to_character()
```

Indeed:

```
sage: char.values()
[3, 1, -1, 0, -1]
```

Alternatively one could implement the [Murnaghan–Nakayama rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murnaghan%E2%80%93Nakayama_rule).